# swift - Use of unresolved identifier 'ns'

Tags: swift

I am unable to resolve this problem, I am migrating a version 1.2 to 2.0

```
@IBAction func btnNext1_click(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.first = false;
    let c = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Welcome2") );
    self.presentViewController(c, animated: true, completion: nil);
    if (UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")) {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let ns = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        };
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(ns);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're declaring "ns" within the "if" block, so it's not available to the statement outside the block. Either move that statement into the "if" block, or else make ns an optional var, declared before the "if" block.

Comment: @ElmerCat Make thate an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would shift the registration method into the if statement:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
  let ns = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: nil)

  UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(ns);
} else {
  // Fallback for earlier iOS versions
};
```