# How to use iOS 8.0 APIs in Swift, when minium target platform is iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, swift

Today, I was learning Notification. Under the **registerUserNotificationSettings(_:)** definition, in the UIApplication Class Reference, it says

> "Prior to scheduling any local notifications, you must call the registerUserNotificationSettings method to let the system know what types of alerts, if any, you plan to display to the user."

But **registerUserNotificationSettings** is only available in iOS 8.0 or later. So how to make it compatible with iOS 7 if I use Swift?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898136/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier-ns?s=3|0.7723 The answer and question should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code inside an if statement to check ios version.

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
  // ios 8 and newer 
}
else {
  // ios 7 and older
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Availability checking in Swift 2 and use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes for iOS7

Example:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let options: UIUserNotificationType =   [
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert,
            UIUserNotificationType.Badge,
            UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        ]

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: options, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    } else {
        let options: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(options)
    }
```